# How can I make a smooth IVY growth coming from the woman's hands to the wall?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I am using Ivy generator plugin to build this ivy and there's an option that you may intersect a place with an object. My idea is to start from 0% IVY and grow it from her hand towards the whole wall in a smooth way.

Is there maybe a way to invert the emitter object so i can do that or any other ideas?

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tkj754l97qo71mi/AAA-7UaqTvGSs8VcPa2cCDKKa?dl=0

link includes: ivy setup screen record and test with baga pie plugin for the idea (but its quite janky so far)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.